# Permanently untick "Manage Version and Build Number" checkbox in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment

**Background**

A couple of weeks ago, we hunted down a dependency bug where we had to ask the authors for help. They then investigated and asked us to untick this setting in Xcode, **"Manage Version and Build Number"**, and it helped. The bug vanished. However, every time I make a deployment, this checkbox is ticked and I have to manually untick it.

**Question**

Is there any way to get this **"Manage Version and Build Number"** checkbox permanently/by default unticked? So it remains unticked every time I make a deployment?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a way to disable this "feature"? Having to uncheck it every time I create a new release is becoming very annoying...

Comment: Use [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/)…

Comment: in Xcode 15.0.1 Not even getting any such option