# How do I use Xcode's new "Manage Version and Build Number" setting?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, versioning

Traditionally, I used to [manage build and version numbers with Apple's agvtool](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1827/_index.html) and/or build scripts. However, when uploading an archive to App Store Connect, I noticed that there is now a new option:

> **Manage Version and Build Number**
> Archive's build number does not meet App Store Connect requirements. This will change the version and build number of all content in your app to 1.0 (2).

I was expecting this to automatically update my target's Version and Build numbers. Instead, I see that it doesn't update *version numbers* at all; and, although it updates the *build number*, it only does so in the archive, so my Xcode project shows a stale value.

How do I get this new feature to update my target's Version and Build numbers?

---

For reference, this is what a new project in Xcode 14 (SwiftUI Interface) looks like...

The **Info.plist** is no longer auto-created. Instead, the target's **Info** tab shows **Bundle version string (short)** ([`CFBundleShortVersionString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring)) and **Bundle version** ([`CFBundleVersion`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion)) hard-coded to the values `${MARKETING_VERSION}` and `${CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION}`, respectively:

[image]

I say "hard-coded" because no matter what I try (deleting them, updating them, or redefining a value like `CFBundleShortVersionString` in an Info.plist) the two settings are reset to look like the screenshot above, upon navigating back to the Info tab.

Also note that `MARKETING_VERSION` defaults to `1.0` (which is odd since [the `CFBundleShortVersionString` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring) clearly states it must be 3 integers); while `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` defaults to `1`.

Attempting to change the bundle values in the **General** tab simply changes the backing property's value (e.g. `MARKETING_VERSION` for "Version").

Answer (score 4):

Unless someone has a better answer, this is what I've been able to glean/guess so far...

1. The ["Distribute apps in Xcode with cloud signing" WWDC 2021 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10204/?time=685) mentions it only increments *build numbers* in the *archive*:

   > New in Xcode 13, if Xcode detects I am distributing with a **build number** that has already been used on App Store Connect, or that is not incrementing, it will offer to increment the build number **in the archive** to one that is valid. [emphasis added]
2. [This answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690647?answerId=689925022#689925022) quotes the following from the Xcode release notes, which again suggests it only increments build numbers, and only updates the archive:

   > When uploading an app to App Store Connect, the distribution assistant in Xcode detects whether your app has a **valid build number (CFBundleVersion)**. If your app has an invalid number (like one that was used previously, or precedes your current build number), the distribution assistant provides an option to automatically increment it to a valid number. In addition, the distribution assistant ensures that the **build numbers** of all embedded content in your app (such as app extensions, App Clips, or watchOS apps) are in sync with your app. Note that this **doesn’t modify your source code or your archive; Xcode updates the build number in a staged copy of your app** before packaging and uploading it to App Store Connect. (59826409) [emphasis added]
3. The "Manage Version and Build Number" feature is poorly named. While Build Numbers are incremented, Version Numbers are only updated [in embedded frameworks, to keep them in sync with the main app](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690647). This is [often undesirable](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690647?answerId=689903022#689903022), and probably [why people are looking to permanently disable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69895802/permanently-untick-manage-version-and-build-number-checkbox-in-xcode).

---

In summary:

- If you don't have embedded frameworks, then using this feature to increment build numbers is fine. Keep in mind that your target's build numbers won't be updated though.
- Whenever you need to increment the version number, you need to manually increment it.

Comment: "Manage Build Number *Conflicts*" might have been a better name. I have mixed feelings. The description is very confusing (and somewhat inaccurate), but during the phase when I'm doing early development (up to test flight), this feature is useful. When I get near the end, I want to make sure the literal version/build info is in GIT.